# Is my Willow Tree dying or just needing TLC

Tags: tree-care, dead-branch

I just bought a home with a huge Willow in the front yard. It has a lot of dead branches and doesn’t look as full as other willows in the area. I’m wondering if there’s anything I can do to make it healthy again or is it too late.[image] I’m not sure how long the tree has been here but the house is a little over 30 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know this willow, but hanging willows are susceptible to water deprivation. They die back when people go on vacation when the trees rely on sewage or greywater. If this tree is near the drain pipes then this might be the case.